# Please help me understand: <textarea> onkey=Javascript

Tags: javascript, split, logical-operators

Please help me understand this line:

`<textarea onkeyup='this.rows = (this.value.split("\n").length||1);' style="overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>`

I understand most of this line, but there are a few areas that I'm getting stuck at specifically in the onkeyup script...

1. I understand `this.value.split("\n")`, but how does it get the length of the split?
2. `||1` = "or 1" right? So how does this fit in?

Answer (score 1):

`this.value` is a string value.

Javascript strings have a `split` function, which returns a string array.

String arrays have a length.

In javascript, 0 is treated as false.

So, set `this.rows` equal to the number of strings resulting from splitting the input by the newline character.  If this number is 0, then set it to 1 instead.